# How do you cook margarine with brown sugar without separating?

Tags: brown-sugar, melting, margarine, passover

I have a recipe that calls for melting margarine, adding brown sugar, and boiling a few minutes before pouring it over matzah boards. The problem is that the margarine separates, and the brown sugar never totally dissolves.

Comment: While this technically isn't specific to [passover], I'm adding that tag because passover recipes have you doing all kinds of crazy things with margarine.

Comment: What kind of brown sugar are you using? I can imagine granulated sugar not dissolving, but soft brown/demerara should dissolve without a problem.

Comment: maybe start the sugar off with a few drops of water to get it to dissolve? The boiling off, I am guessing, is to lose all the water from the marg so that bit extra will evap too.

Comment: Is this specific to passover? I thought people learned long ago not to use margarine for anything.

Comment: @Rob For people who keep Kosher, one of the prohibitions is mixing meat and dairy. If someone wants to serve dessert after a meat meal, they don't use dairy in that dessert. Margarine or other dairy-free alternatives are often used instead of butter.

Answer (score 3):

I’ve had this problem several times with melting brown sugar and butter together and boiling it. The key is to start on a lower temperature, stirring the brown sugar and butter as it melts. Allow the mixture to slowly get to a boil and then leave it-allow it to boil on its own evaporating some of the liquid. Never do this on high temperature-it wrecks it every time!

Answer (score 1):

I assume we are making candy or fudge.  Heat the brown sugar first when you have it to temperature, stir in the margarine off the heat then pour it.

Answer (score 1):

I just had the problem 2 batches in a row.  The 3rd time, I made sure that the margarine was at room temp (not directly from the fridge).  I then started heating at a low temp instead of medium so that it heated more slowly.  This batch worked perfectly